# Calculate percentage of students SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to calculate percentage of students with higher mark than average for each course?

Assume I have a table (avg_marks) with average marks for each course and number of students in the course:

```
course_id    avg_mark    num_students
12345        74          20
12346        70          17
12347        64          33
...
```

I also have a table (enrolments) with all courses, students enrolled in those courses and their mark for the course:

```
course_id    student     mark
12345        1010        63
12345        2111        75
12345        3221        85
12345        6788        40
...    
12347        8989        90
...
```

The expected output would be the table with course id and percentage of students with higher marks than average:

```
course_id    percentage
12345        40
12345        20
12346        50
...
```

I have calculated number of students who have higher mark than average, but somehow I wasn't able to calculate the percentage (perhaps because the table contains all courses?). How can I modify this query or make a new one to calculate the percentage of students with higher mark than average?

Number of students with higher than average mark:

```
SELECT e.course_id, COUNT(e.student)
FROM enrolments e, avg_mark av
WHERE e.mark > av.avg_mark AND e.course_id=av.course_id
```

Output of the above query was like the following:

```
course_id     count 
12345         5
12346         10
12347         8
...
```

Comment: Why do you need avg_marks? You have all the data you need in enrolments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the table `avg_marks`.
Use window function `AVG()` in `enrolments` to get the average `mark` for each `course_id` and then use conditional aggregation with `AVG()` aggregate function to get the percentage:

```
SELECT course_id, 
       ROUND(100 * AVG((mark > avg_mark)::int)) percentage 
FROM (SELECT *, AVG(mark) OVER (PARTITION BY course_id) avg_mark FROM enrolments) e 
GROUP BY course_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a9ed44c4bc4b05e4ab701cfccb255b25).

Comment: "You don't need the table `avg_marks`." -- They not only not need it, it is actually harmful as it contains redundant data that can lead to inconsistencies.

Comment: Can you please explain `ROUND(100 * AVG((mark > avg_mark)::int)) percentage` ?

Comment: Also, what if I also need to select only courses that have at least 12 students? This is what I was using `avg_marks` table for.

Comment: `mark>avg_mark` returns true or false and then `(mark > avg_mark)::int)` converts it to 1 or 0. So `AVG((mark > avg_mark)::int)` returns the average number of these 1s and 0s which is multiplied by 100 and rounded to an integer. This is the percentage that you want. For at least 12 students add at the end `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 12`

Comment: @DSzum also I suggest to use `>=` instead of `>` as the condition, because say there are 12 students in a course and they all get the same mark 50, then the average will be 50 and with the condition `mark>avg_mark` you will get 0 as percentage.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    e.course_id, 
    count(case when e.mark > av.avg_mark then e.student end)/count(*) * 100 as students_cnt_with_mark_above_avg_pct 
from enrolments e, avg_mark av
where e.course_id = av.course_id
group by e.course_id
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this code is pretty self explanatory